# Confusion regarding the sign of the work of a force

Tags: work

The work of a force is given by the following line integral:
\begin{equation}
W=\int_{A}^{B}\vec{F}\cdot \vec{dl}
\end{equation}

So the work that is needed for an electric particle to be moved in an electric filed is given by the following line integral:
\begin{equation}
W=\int_{A}^{B}\vec{F}\cdot \vec{dl}=q\int_{a}^{B}\vec{E}\cdot \vec{dl}
\end{equation}

Whether the particle moves with the help of the electric field or with the help of a force that we exert will decided by the sign or the result so:

If $W>0$ then the particle moves by the field and if $W<0$ then we must exert a force upon it to be moved.

This is what I know. But I am reading a textbook that says that if a particle is moved by a force that we exert then the work is given by the following line integral:
\begin{equation}
W=\int_{A}^{B}\vec{F}\cdot \vec{dl}=-q\int_{a}^{B}\vec{E}\cdot \vec{dl}
\end{equation}

Isn't this wrong it its current form? Won't it reverse the sign of the result?

If this were stated as:
\begin{equation}
W=\int_{A}^{B}\vec{F}\cdot \vec{dl}=-\left|q\int_{a}^{B}\vec{E}\cdot \vec{dl}\right|
\end{equation}

in order to emphasise that the work should be negative, it would be correct but in its current form I believe that it is wrong. Am I right?

Comment: "If W>0 then the particle moves by the field and if W<0 then we must exert a force upon it to be moved" is wrong: The (positively charged) particle could have an initial speed that makes it move against the electric field and is slowing down between A and B.

Comment: @brucesmitherson haha you are correct but I am merely writing the elxplanation that is in the textbooks not some more advanced cases that might occur. :P

Comment: then the book is wrong :)

Comment: @brucesmitherson If we want to be 100% correct yes they are. :P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The book said that 
\begin{equation}
W=\int_{A}^{B}\vec{F_{us}}\cdot \vec{dl}=-q\int_{a}^{B}\vec{E}\cdot \vec{dl} =-\int_{A}^{B}\vec{F_{e}}\cdot \vec{dl}
\end{equation}

which is alright as the work done by us without acceleration is equal and opposite to that done by the electric field since the direction of force exerted by us is opposite to that exerted by the electric field. That is the origin of the $W>0/W<0$ arguments as mentioned by you in the question. So it makes sense. I believe the confusion is cleared now.

If you put modulus then you won't be able to distinguish positive charge from the negative charge so that is a strict no.